# How to find all read-write memory address of a process in Linux/UNIX with C/C++ language?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, mapping, procfs

Through /proc file system , it's probable to read memory mappings with /proc/PID_PROCESS/maps , but is there any native APIs that dedicated for this function in C/C++ ?

i.e to find out memory address that are writable and readable for process with PID 9322:

```
%> awk -F "-| " '$3 ~ /rw/ { print $1 " " $2}' /proc/9322/maps
0804e000 0804f000
085ed000 0860e000
b7707000 b7708000
b7864000 b7865000
b7865000 b7868000
b7897000 b7898000
b78b6000 b78b7000
bfd2e000 bfd50000
```

And those address are passed into my program , but now i want to integrate this function directly into my C++ program.

For most effectiveness , if i want to support for other *BSD system , i would not be able to take advantage of /proc system , and i think there should some method to generate e.g /proc/1/maps directly without reading them again there , correct if i'm wrong ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the proc file like you read normal file.

eg.

```
  FILE *filep = fopen("/proc/9322/maps","r");
  char ch;
  while (ch != EOF){
    ch = fgetc(filep);
    printf("%c", ch);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Zim , but is there any native API's that i don't need to parse /proc file system ? Because on some BSD UNIX system , there's no /proc file system , i would be happy if my program is portable amid most of *BSD system ;-P

Comment: AFAIK there is no native API for that. You can write parser for each BSD, Linux and selectively compile using flags.

Comment: Sure , and i've implemented one with simple file reading and parsing , i'll take this one as the best answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could grab the PID of the process using:

```
pid_t pid = getpid();
```

Then, you could open the file /proc/PID/maps to and parse it into an array to determine which sets of memory are read-write.

Edit: The getpid() function requires `#include <unistd.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no full library (to my knowledge) to do what you want here. There is a `libproc` as part of procps, however this is an internal API, and moreover probably only implements the functionality used by procps. It would certainly be nice if there was such a library - feel free to release one! - but for now you'll have to conditional-compile for each OS you're targetting, and use OS-specific APIs (for Linux, directly opening and reading the appropriate procfiles) directly.

Comment: Thanks for answering this questing , i didn't really tried libproc , but you are right , i should try to release one ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these questions and answers:

- [Searching a process' memory on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839724/searching-a-process-memory-on-linux/3019872#3019872)
- [Dump memory of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342335/dump-memory-of-a-process/3344402#3344402)
- [Low-overhead way to access the memory space of a traced process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958369/low-overhead-way-to-access-the-memory-space-of-a-traced-process/2260225#2260225)